# Puppeteer evaluate returns undefined for an array of DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a table on a website and I want to scrape all tds with `class='col-sm-1 available-day'`.

Using Puppeteer I tried like this:

```
 let result = await page.evaluate(() => {

     return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.col-sm-1.available-day'));
});
```

But when I try to output the result it says that is undefined. How can I return an array of DOM nodes from `evaluate`?

Comment: Can you show the full undefined error? What exactly is undefined?

Comment: There is no error , when I type console.log(result) it says just : undefined

Comment: You can't return elements with evaluate, try evaluateHandle or otherwise return just text

Comment: There's also `page.$$` if you want an array of ElementHandles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `document.querySelectorAll` gets DOM nodes which are complex object that cannot be returned from `page.evaluate`.

You need to return simple objects that can be serialized, for example, here we are returning an array of text values for the selected elements:

```
let result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.col-sm-1.available-day'));
  return tds.map((td) => td.innerText);
});
```

Comment: Thank you , works <3 . I have one more question : so now the result its defined but has 0 values in it. When I go to my url from which I want to scrape some data  ( https://www.drpciv.ro/ ) and I try to take a screenshot it shows blank. Any idea why I am not able to reach that url with puppeteer ?

Comment: Maybe they don't want puppeteer to access their site (in that case research how to change user agent).