# Why page.$$eval and evaluate return undefined

Tags: puppeteer

Let's say I will go to google.com then fetch all `a` tags inside the page, so I write something as below

```
await page
  .goto ("https://google.com")
  .then (() => page.$$eval ("a", xs => xs.length))
  .then (console.log)
```

this will print a number that's greater than 0, which means that `xs` is an array full of `<a>` html elements. Good

However once I change it to the following

```
await page
  .goto ("https://google.com")
  .then (() => page.$$eval ("a", xs => xs))
  .then (console.log)
```

it returns `undefined` ??? this is weird and confusing why would it return undefined it doesn't make any sense

is this a bug or something !

Comment: It does make sense. DOM nodes aren't serializable, and you can't do anything with them back in NodeJS, only in the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get elements from page.evaluate in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032903/get-elements-from-page-evaluate-in-puppeteer). Also [Puppeteer evaluate returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216965/puppeteer-evaluate-returns-undefined) and others.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your reply. It makes sense now however **it should be mentioned in the documentation !**

From the official docs: *"If it returns an element it is wrapped in an ElementHandle, else the raw value itself is returned."*
  
`the raw value itself`?? not undefined ... this is why it was confusing

I will update with an answer to help whoever comes to this problem in the future

Comment: You can make a PR for the docs if you're not happy with the description.